# Check the string from the database that it is available or not

Tags: php, mysql

if(!empty($coupon_code)){

```
            if(isset($coupon_code)){
                $coupon = trim($coupon_code);        
                $checkcoupon = "SELECT couponCode FROM cc WHERE couponCode='".$coupon."'"; 
                $results_coupon = mysqli_query($dbc,$checkcoupon);    
                if(mysqli_num_rows($results_coupon) == 1) {   
                echo true; 
            } 

            else { 
                echo false; 
            }   
        }
```

When i am passing an input it requires to check the input string from the database and then validate it whether it is correct or wrong. But it is not working. For debugging i was using $_GET['coupon'] but it is still appearing on the address bar.

```
<form method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" >
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label"></label> 
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="input-group mb-3"> <input id="coupon" class="form-control" name="coupon" type="text" size="50" maxlength="13" /> </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" id="btn_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button> 
</form>
```

For the database i am using this code.

```
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '';
$db_name = 'test';

$dbc = mysqli_connect ($db_hostname,$db_username, $db_password,$db_name);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
   echo "Could not establish database connection!";
   exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not posted complete code, use this code and let me know if it works

```
if(isset($_GET['coupon'])){
    $coupon = trim($_GET['coupon']);        
    $checkcoupon = "SELECT couponCode FROM cc WHERE couponCode='".$coupon."'"; 
    $results_coupon = mysqli_query($dbc,$checkcoupon);    
    if(mysqli_num_rows($results_coupon) == 1) {   
    return true; 
}else{ 
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Comment: <form  method="get" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" >
 
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label"></label>
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group mb-3">
   <input id="coupon" class="form-control" name="coupon" type="text" size="50" maxlength="13" />
 </div>
   </div>
 

</div>



  
    <button type="submit" id="btn_submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

Comment: Please do **NOT** use this as is. This code contains a SQL injection by using a value from `$_GET` in the query without escaping. See [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: @AmandeepSingh it is still not working.Now i have put complete code of my work.

Comment: If you have access to phpmyadmin run this query and check the results. SELECT couponCode FROM cc WHERE couponCode= 'coupon_code'